# How to find the max of this function over this strange interval?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

> $$\max_{x\in [0, 1] \cup \mathbb{N}} xe^{-x^2}$$

So I thought: $[0, 1]$ is compact, hence Weiestrass Theorem holds. $\mathbb{N}$ is not compact instead.

$$f'(x) = e^{-x^2}(1-2x^2)$$

So the zeros are $x = \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and I have to trash the negative one.

Now

$$f(0) = 0$$
$$f(1) = 1/e$$
$$f(1/\sqrt{2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2e}}$$

I would say the minimum occurrs at $x = 1/\sqrt{2}$ but I really cannot understand how to treat the $\mathbb{N}$ part.

I mean I know that as $n\to +\infty,\ f(n) \to 0$ but this doesn't help me.

Also I was wondering: does the function has a minimum too? Is there a non empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in which the function has no absolute maximum?

Comment: Solve for when $f'<0$ and evaluate all points in your domain for which $f'\geq 0$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang $f' > 0$ when $0<x<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $f'\left(x\right) \leq 0$ for $x \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, so the function is non-increasing in the interval $\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, +\infty)\right]$, since $\mathbb{N}$ is in this interval, the maximum will be at the point $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Thank you! I was indeed obtaining the same thanks to the other user's comment. Can you please tell me if I'm right in saying the minimum is at zero instead? :)

Comment: @Numb3rs $x \geq 0$ in $\left[0,1\right] \cup \mathbb{N}$ and exponential is always positive, so $f\left(x\right) \geq 0$, so yes, the minimum is at zero.